# Any good resource for mysql indexing and locking explanation

Tags: mysql

Is there any good website/resource where it is clearly defined how indexing helps and locking happens by which query?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

This resource is helpful to explain how to analyse locks and deadlocks:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks/

Also this query will display table use:

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE table LIKE '%[TABLE_NAME]%' AND Database LIKE '[DBNAME]' AND In_use > 0;
```